# Using PCRE_MULTILINE with a caret

Tags: c, regex, pcre

In a C code, I need to check if a pattern matches on at least one line of a file. I need a caret in my expression. What I have is:

```
const char *disambiguate_pp(SourceFile *sourcefile) {
        char *p = ohcount_sourcefile_get_contents(sourcefile);
  char *eof = p + ohcount_sourcefile_get_contents_size(sourcefile);

        /* prepare regular expressions */
        pcre *re;
        const char *error;
        int erroffset;
        re = pcre_compile("^\\s*(define\\s+[\\w:-]+\\s*\\(|class\\s+[\\w:-]+(\\s+inherits\\s+[\\w:-]+)?\\s*{|node\\s+\\'[\\w:\\.-]+\\'\\s*{)",
                          PCRE_MULTILINE, &error, &erroffset, NULL);

        for (; p < eof; p++) {
                if (pcre_exec(re, NULL, p, mystrnlen(p, 100), 0, 0, NULL, 0) > -1)
                        return LANG_PUPPET;

        }
        return LANG_PASCAL;
}
```

For some reason, the caret seems ignored, as the following line matches the regexp (and should not):

```
  // update the package block define template (the container for all other
```

I tried a lot of things, but could not get this working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you looping `for (; p < eof; p++)`? Wouldn't `p` eventually point right at `define`, so it becomes first in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `PCRE_MULTILINE`, you pass it the whole buffer as a single string, and it tells you whether there is a match anywhere in the string. The `for` loop is not only superfluous, it will erroneously make PCRE think it is looking at the beginning of the string (hence also beginning of line) when you pass it a position in the middle of the buffer.

Comment: Thank you. For the record, I added my final code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Mode modifier` for this reason. Using `(?m)` at the start of a pattern would treat any caret(`^`) as line break.

- Dot matches newline: Turn this on the make the dot match any
  character, including line break characters. When off, the dot will
  match any character except line break characters. This is sometimes
  called `“single line mode”` and corresponds with the «`(?s)`»
  mode modifier in Perl-style regular expressions.
- Case insensitive: By default, regular expressions are case sensitive,
  and «cat» will not match “CAT”. Turn this on to make these match. The
  corresponding mode modifier is «`(?i)`».
- `^$` match at line breaks: When off, the anchors «`^`» and
  «`$`» only match at the start and the end of the string,
  respectively. When on, they also match after and before line breaks
  in the string (i.e. at the start and the end of lines). Note that in
  some regex flavors that lack this option, «`^`» and «`$`» always
  match at line breaks. This option is sometimes called “multi-line
  mode” and its mode modifier is «`(?m)`».
- Free-spacing: Normally, any spaces and line breaks you type into your
  regular expressions are matched literally. In free-spacing mode,
  whitespace is ignored and comments can be started with a #. This is
  sometimes called extended or expanded mode, and the usual modifier is
  «`(?x)`».

**UPDATE**

Looking at you RegEx properly I recognize that there is a missing parenthesis at the end of the pattern and there is an `Empty alternative`. Change it to:

```
pcre *myregexp;
const char *error;
int erroroffset;
int offsetcount;
int offsets[(2+1)*3]; // (max_capturing_groups+1)*3
myregexp = pcre_compile("^\\s*(define\\s+[\\w:-]+\\s*\\(class\\s+[\\w:-]+(\\s+inherits\\s+[\\w:-]+)?\\s*\\{|node\\s+\\Z[\\w:.-]+\\Z\\s*\\{)", 0, &error, &erroroffset, NULL);
if (myregexp != NULL) {
    offsetcount = pcre_exec(myregexp, NULL, subject, strlen(subject), 0, 0, offsets, (2+1)*3);
    while (offsetcount > 0) {
        // match offset = offsets[0];
        // match length = offsets[1] - offsets[0];
        if (pcre_get_substring(subject, &offsets, offsetcount, 0, &result) >= 0) {
            // Do something with match we just stored into result
        }
        offsetcount = pcre_exec(myregexp, NULL, subject, strlen(subject), 0, offsets[1], offsets, (2+1)*3);
    } 
} else {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression at erroroffset
}
```

---

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I used @tripleee's answer and this is my final code:

```
const char *disambiguate_pp(SourceFile *sourcefile) {
        char *p = ohcount_sourcefile_get_contents(sourcefile);
  char *eof = p + ohcount_sourcefile_get_contents_size(sourcefile);

        /* prepare regular expressions */
        pcre *re;
        const char *error;
        int erroffset;
        re = pcre_compile("^\\s*(define\\s+[\\w:-]+\\s*\\(|class\\s+[\\w:-]+(\\s+inherits\\s+[\\w:-]+)?\\s*{|node\\s+\\'[\\w:\\.-]+\\'\\s*{)",
                          PCRE_MULTILINE, &error, &erroffset, NULL);

        /* regexp for checking for define and class declarations */
        if (pcre_exec(re, NULL, p, mystrnlen(p, 10000), 0, 0, NULL, 0) > -1)            
                return LANG_PUPPET;

        return LANG_PASCAL;
}
```